# ModuleNotFoundError for pandas_datareader: Jupyter Notebook using different packages from conda environment

Tags: pandas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda, pandas-datareader

I am using Anaconda windows v5.3.

I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

When I tried to print out the packages used by Jupyter Notebook, I realized that pandas_datareader is not in, and a different version of pandas (0.23.0) is used:

```
import pkg_resources
for i in pkg_resources.working_set:
    print(i)
```

## Output

```
...
pandocfilters 1.4.2
pandas 0.23.0
packaging 17.1
openpyxl 2.5.3
...
```

This differs from the library installed in the pyfinance environment:

```
>conda list

# Name                    Version                   Build

pandas                    0.20.3                   py36_0

pandas-datareader         0.4.0                    py36_0
```

Hence, pandas_datareader seem to work in the python shell in the command prompt, but not in jupyter notebook. Are there anyways to sync jupyter notebook environment to the conda environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized to sync jupyter notebook you just have to do:

> conda install jupyter